# passing an array within another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

The problem is actually, there is an array containing a number of arrays. I have to print the elements of one of the sub arrays named 'list'. But I have a problem to fetch the subarray while using foreach loop.

The following code is:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    $arr1=$value[$list];
    echo $arr1;   
}
```

Comment: can you post your array ?? Please update your question with your array .

Comment: show your `$arr` and `$list` data

Comment: $value[$list] uses the variable $list - try $value['list'] instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be:-

```
// declare second array outside loop
$arr1 = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{  
    // list is a key in $value array then you can access via below way
    $arr1[] = $value['list'];
}
// print Array using print_r() function outside loop  
print_r($arr1);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If your array like in below format

```
<?php
$arr = array(
            'key' => array('array elements here'),
            'list' => array('array elements here'),
            'key' => ........
        );
?>
```

you can use below to get only list array

```
<?php
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{  
    if($key == 'list') {
    $arr1=$value['list'];
    break;
    }
}

print_r($arr1); 

?>
```